# How to write return statement in java array function

Tags: java

I was writing this code, and I am not able to resolve this error **missing return statement**. Tried but still, nothing happened.

```
public class Solution {

    static int[] getRecord(int[] s){


   // Complete this function
    int bada=0,chota=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        int heighst=s[0];
        int lowest=s[0];
        if(s[i]<s[i+1]){
          heighst=s[i+1];
            bada++;

        }
        if(s[i]>s[i+1]){
            lowest=s[0];
            chota++;

        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] s = new int[n];
    for(int s_i=0; s_i < n; s_i++){
        s[s_i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    int[] result = getRecord(s);
    String separator = "", delimiter = " ";
    for (Integer val : result) {
        System.out.print(separator + val);
        separator = delimiter;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

Comment: `getRecord` is missing a return statement.

Comment: Add return s in your first method.

Comment: @Yash Why? It does not change

Comment: Seems like you need to the objective of the getRecord function.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes sir, but he just wants the function, right. Doesn't have a motive for it. :P

Answer (score 3):

Your `getRecord` is counting things in `bada` and `chota`, which are local variables to that function, and so nothing else can access them. The function serves no purpose unless it returns them (and/or `heighst` [sic] and `lowest`).

Since there are multiple things to return, you need some kind of structure to return them in — an object or an array.

Apparently you or your instructor have chosen to use an array for that, so you need to create an `int` array with enough slots for the things you want to return, put those things (e.g., `bada`, `chota`, `heighst` [sic] and/or `lowest`) in it, and return that array.

---

**This answer purposefully does not contain code.** The OP is clearly working on an assignment, handing them the answer rather than *leading* them to the answer probably won't help them learn.

Comment: @rhujhaan another hint is to consider when and how often your variables `lowest`, `highest` will be initialized